# Why there is a white line on the edge while using canvas destination-over

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

When the size of canvas is not large enough and there is a curve of shape, there will be a white line on the edge of two layers. This just happen in the newest chrome, older or IE or FF work well.

```js
var canvas= $('#a')[0];
ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

canvas.width = 200;
canvas.height = 200;
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-over';
ctx.arc(50, 50, 100, 0, Math.PI * 2);
ctx.fill();
ctx.arc(100, 100, 100, 0, Math.PI * 2);
ctx.fill();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="a"></canvas>
```

You could see the demo from following codepen: 
[codepen demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yYmZEL?editors=101)

Comment: Can't repro on mac but this seems to be an anti-aliasing bug. You shoudl report the issue.

Comment: Can't see anything, but I am on chrome Beta and windows 10. I have had a similar sounding problem with it suddenly appearing after a beta chrome update some months back. Using `destination-over` and also with `source-atop`. Never found a fix I even sent in a bug report, they found nothing. I found that the canvas size affected it (try 450 * 300 canvas mine stopped doing it at that size). As I saw nothing on your snippet I went and checked my app and it's not doing it any more. The white would get worse the more I rendered. Also occasional affected clearRect leaving pixels behind.

Comment: @Blindman67 eh, but the snippet works on my computer. Yes, I founded this when I make an animation, the  white get much worse! Indeed, It affected by canvas size.

Comment: Sounds like the same problem. I was running windows 7 then. I have only recently moved to windows 10, so mine may have fixed via chrome update or the windows upgrade. Also using NVIDIA Geforce GT 330M graphics card. I cant help as I never found a way to stop it. I just stopped using `destination-over` and `source-atop`